# How long after season 1 is season 2 of Helix?

Tags: helix

One of the distinct touches that *Helix* used during its first season was a indicator at the start of each episode that stated what Day it was.  That is, how many days since the CDC team showed up and started dealing with the outbreak.  This was also a handy tool to keep track of the chronology of events, especially given the events of the season finale.

Which brings me to season 2, where they've reset the clock back to 'Day 1' for the events on the island.  There are mentions of time passing since the last Day of season 1, but I didn't catch a clear mention of how long it's been since the end of season 1.

Which 'Day' of season 1 would the premiere of season 2 be set on?  How long has it been since the end of season 1?

Comment: On of the characters mentions that she hasn't heard from the former team lead in "over a year"; that implies that it's more than one year, but less than two years, since the conclusion of the previous season.  Beyond that, I don't think that we were given any distinct clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About a year and a half.**

There was [a press conference with the show runner, Steven Maeda](http://www.reellifewithjane.com/2015/01/steven-maeda-neil-napier-talk-helix/), where he gave a rough estimate for the time lapsed since the end of season one (spoilers for s01e13):

> We’re probably about a year and a half ahead of the destruction of Arctic Biosystems from last season.

Answer (score 1):

Sarah mentions she's been pregnant for 15 months so that should indicate how long after season 1 season two starts.